# 400 Error on certain routes (Django + gunicorn + nginx)

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I have a django site I am trying to deploy with gunicorn and nginx.  All routes work fine except for those with hyphens.  These return a 400 error.

I have `debug` set to `True`, so it is not the `allowed_hosts` issue I keep reading about.  It is not a problem with my regexp either.  The site works as is on Apache.

Here is my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80 default;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name mydomain.local

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }

location /static/ {
   alias /path/to/project/static/;
}

location /uploads/ {
   alias /path/to/project/uploads/;
}

location @proxy_to_app {
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
   proxy_redirect off;
   proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8002;
}
```

}

And here is my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
import settings

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', 'Portfolio.views.get_home', name='home'),
    url(r'^contact/$', 'Portfolio.views.get_contact', name='contact'),
    url(r'^grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', 'Portfolio.views.get_gallery', name='gallery')
)
```

As I said, it is only slugs containing a hyphen that cause the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a semicolon after the `server_name` directive.

Error 400 with nginx is usually related to a configuration error causing incomplete or wrong data being passed to the application. This hypothesis is reinforced by your statement that under apache it works fine.

You should thus run gunicorn with a high log level (`--log-level debug`) and see what it gets passed by the web server. See the difference in the requests between running apache and nginx. This should help you find the cause of the error, which by itself is very generic.

Comment: I made that error when subbing out my actual domain with `mydomain.local`.